# force entering proper format phone phone number in excel

Tags: excel

Is there a way in Microsfot Excel to force entering in a column properly formatted phone numbers with the international code?

I mean phone number with the format:

*+1 12345678

+44 1231231

0044 123123132*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Way 1**

There, go into excel, right click on a cell, or range of cells, or even the entire column you wish to force format and click on format cells, once you are there you will see this below:

[image: Phoe Code]

Once there, click on the **Number tab** if it isn't selected already, and click as shown as the **Custom** category and type in the **Type:** the format as shown above `+## ####### ####`.

This will allow you to do what you want. I hope this helps.

**Way 2**

Another way to do it is to use conditional formatting. I linked to a worksheet below that has the conditional formatting.  I have made it so a cell is where you type in **US**, **UK**, **Other** and the format changes. Again, it may not be your perfect answer, but it is one of many ways to do it...

http://www.kaboomlabs.com/excel/examples/CF.xlsx

Comment: The problem is that I need to allow entering a different number of numbers. The only thing that I need to force is that either the useer enter the + or the 00 followed by the national code (that can have a variable number of digits) and a variable number of digits for the number

Comment: The way I showed is an absolute way... The other way would be conditional formatting. Are the ways you want above the only ways? Also are they specific to countries or this is for you only?

Comment: The problem I am seeing though is two of these are identical in lenght, there is no real way to differentiate the two unless you dictate a specific format, and that is through Conditional Formatting, unless you dictate through a refrence cell what country you are formatting for that is.

Comment: @delemere updated answer, you can change the verification names to whatever you want, but this will work as long as the person using it knows to change the refrence cell name.  You could make it into a drop down list if you really wanted to, but that's another kettle of fish and another question.

Comment: It is not exactly what I needed but I'm setting the answer as correct since it looks like there isn't another way

Comment: If I figure out another way, I'll help. If you show a concept of what you have in mind, by uploading a sheet. I may be able to custom my answer more towards what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Formula as the condition for data-validation:

```
=OR(LEFT(E1,1)="+",LEFT(E1,2)="00")
```

[image]

[Here](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/11/25/search-for-multiple-text-strings-in-multiple-cells-and-use-in-data-validation-in-excel/) you can see how you use data-validation

Comment: ok this is useful although it is not exactly what I need. I thought there was a way just to ask excel to check whether the number format is correct

Comment: *to force entering in a column properly formatted phone numbers* - my solution will force this, if applied for a whole column with specific settings. But I guess you want more of an auto-correct approach, which Matt answered so far. The only other way would be the almighty VBA :)

Comment: I was thinking of VBA as well, but sometimes a non-VBA way is good too.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm doing the same as you - I need to enter several differing international numbers in a column which could have different formats, some dialing codes have 3 digits some 2 etc.

However, I have found that adding an apostrophe before the dialing code was the only way I could leave the text (including the two zeros at the front) as I wanted it. The apostrophe apparently tells excel to treat what followed as ordinary text, not as a number.

Easier than typing the apostrophe each time is selecting the entire column and then under the number tab in format cells, choose "text" not custom nor number.

Hope that helps, it certainly helped me!